# What is exactly "container managed object" in Java 6 EE world?

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi

I tried to use CDI for my struts action running on glassfish.
But java dependency injection does not work for it. It works for JSF but not struts.
As I read -- container injects dependencies to any instance of container managed bean (bean created by container).

So, what is "container managed bean"? Any POJO? Or only jsf back bean, ejb-bean and so on?

And how it happens? Glassfish has special class-loader to inject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only can inject your CDI beans in managed classes. Struts creates its own instances, so Struts beans are no container managed.

I don't know if Struts has a plugin able to inject CDI beans, but you can lookup the Bean Manager in JNDI tree.

```
public BeanManager getBeanManager() {
    try {
        Context jndiContext = new InitialContext();
        return (BeanManager) jndiContext.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // handle the exception
    }
}
```

In your application you can use this:

```
BeanManager manager = BeanManagerUtil.getBeanManager();
manager.getBeans(MyClass.class);
```

For each bean returned by getBeans method you need to get the bean reference

```
CreationalContext ctx = manager.createCreationalContext(bean);
MyClass myClass = manager.getReference(bean, MyClass.class, ctx);
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you! But what is "managed class"? Why servlet is managed class while struts action is not?

Comment: when I say "managed" is "managed and instantiated by container". You do not create manually a servlet instance using "new MyServlet". The creation of Servlet is managed by container. Struts classes are instantiated by struts using new, so container doesn't managed this classes.